# C# timespan check if a time is available in the available ranges

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I am creating a simple application to book meeting roomes. I want to write the entityframework query to check if the given time slot is valid so that there is no overlap with the already existing slots.

for eg: if there is already bookings available say for eg; on a given date 10:00 - 14:00 and 15:00 - 17:00. These two slots are availble.
If i try to book a new slot for 10:00 - 12:00 or 09:00 - 11:00 it should not allow. Here is my query

```
public bool SlotAvailable(Item item) {
var result =  _context.bookings
.where(booking=>
    (item.StartTime >= booking.StartTime && item.StartTime <= booking.EndTime) ||
                                                (item.EndTime >= booking.StartTime && item.EndTime <= booking.EndTime);

return result.Any();
}
```

is this the correct and efficient query? Can anyone help with this?

Thanks

Comment: You should search for overlaps with `item.StartTime < booking.EndTime && item.EndTime > booking.StartTime`  Basically if `item` starts before a booking ends and ends after the booking starts means there's overlap.  Then return `!result.Any()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to do is check for any overlaps.  That can be done with `item.StartTime < booking.EndTime && item.EndTime > booking.StartTime` which basically says if your item starts before a booking ends and ends after the booking starts then there is overlap.  Then you only need to determine if there is at least one of these

```
public bool SlotAvailable(Item item) 
{
    return !_context.bookings
        .Any(booking => 
            item.StartTime < booking.EndTime 
            && item.EndTime > booking.StartTime);
}
```

This will determine if there are any overlapping booking and will result in the least amount of data returned from the DB.